# How to change parent of components with SWT?

Tags: java, swt

My window should allow two different kind of layouts (it's a simple example to better illustrate it), e.g.

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Component 1 | Component 2 | Component 3 |
|             |             |             |
|             |             |             |
|             |             |             |
|             |             |             |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

and

```
+-------------+---------------------------+
| Component 1 | Component 2               |
|             |                           |
|             +---------------------------+
|             | Component 3               |
|             |                           |
+-------------+---------------------------+
```

where the user can switch between both, e.g., using a menu item.

With SWT you need to provide the parent when creating a component. But we will need to (1) reuse the component and (2) place them in a different parent (similar to docking frameworks). How is this possible with SWT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do this by changing a component's parent.

`setParent()` changes the control's parent, *if the underlying operating system supports it*. Then you can `layout()` the composite so the changes appear.

Say you have three controls:

- A composite `c1` containing vertical controls
- A composite `c2` containing horizontal controls
- A label `lbl`
- A button `btn`

Here's the code:

```
public class ControlSwitcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        GridLayout gl = new GridLayout();
        gl.marginWidth = gl.marginHeight = 20;
        shell.setLayout(gl);

        final Composite c1 = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        c1.setBackground(new Color(display, 255, 160, 160));
        RowLayout layout = new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL);
        c1.setLayout(layout);

        final Composite c2 = new Composite(c1, SWT.NONE);
        c2.setBackground(new Color(display, 160, 255, 160));
        c2.setLayout(new RowLayout());

        final Label lbl = new Label(c2, SWT.NORMAL);
        lbl.setText("Hello world");

        final Button btn = new Button(c2, SWT.PUSH);
        btn.setText("Switch");
        btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                Composite target;
                if (btn.getParent().equals(c2)) {
                    target = c1;
                } else {
                    target = c2;
                }
                boolean success = btn.setParent(target);
                if (success) {
                    target.pack();
                    shell.pack();
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Not supported by this platform");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know whether setting the parent is supported on Windows, OS X and Linux/GTK?

Comment: No; I've only tested this on Vista. I can check this for you at the office on Monday.

Comment: I've tested it on Linux and it works (assuming GTK+ is installed, which is default on Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Xubuntu).

Comment: I haven't tested it on OS X, but I've done similar things and am fairly certain it isn't a problem on that platform, either.

Comment: Small note: the active control loses focus when the layout changes in this fashion. You might want to execute `setFocus()` after `layout()`.